# Got "syntax error near unexpected end of file" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm making an script that gives me a day like this jjj/yyyy when I give it a day like this dd/mm/yyyy and I need it to have an error when you don't write correctly but I'm starting and it's not working :(

```
#! /bin/bash

#Primero debes ingresar el mes
echo "Ingresa el número de un mes del año"
read mes

#Condicional 
#Dependiendo si coloca bien $mes
if [ "$mes" -lt 12 -a "$mes" -gt 0 ]; then
echo "muy bien, sigamos."
    else
    if [ "$mes" -gt 12 -a "$mes" -lt 0 ]; then
    echo "Creo que eso ya no es un mes!";
exit
fi
```

When I run it it says "syntax error near unexpected end of file"

Comment: [Yes, someone can help you](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3071/33055).

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. A number cannot be at the same time less than 0 and greater than 12, so your second condition can never be true. Also note that `-lt` and `-gt` are for _strictly_ greater. -lt 12 and -gt 0 means from 1 to 11. Use `-le` for less than or equal.

Answer (score 9):

You missed a `fi` for inner `if`:

```
if [ "$mes" -lt 12 -a "$mes" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "muy bien, sigamos."
else
  if [ "$mes" -gt 12 -a "$mes" -lt 0 ]; then
    echo "Creo que eso ya no es un mes!"
    # Missed fi here
  fi
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Now I have another issue, it doesn't display the second if part... I mean, If I put the number 13 it just ends, it doesn't say "Creo que esto ya  no es un mes!"

Comment: @Divshah: `13` is **not** greater than `12` **and** less than `1`

Comment: @Divshah, change your `-a` flag in the second if loop to `-o`.

Comment: Finally I wrote this:

Comment: you can find it in a new answer... please help :(

Answer (score -2):

In the `else if` statement, you need to write it like this:

```
elfi [con]; then echo "statement"
```